# Browse large number of files in Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-explorer

I have a large number of files in one of our datalake folders. I use Azure Storage Explorer to find\download specific files. If I need the latest files, which is usually the case, I go through all the pages to get to last one and this takes a lot of time. Is there an easier way to do this? Or perhaps setup the folder in a descending order based on created timestamp?

[image: storage-explorer files listing halfway through]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the latest file is the file which created/upload latest.

We usually using **Last Modified** to get the latest file. For example, I have 300+ blobs in a folder, the **Last Modified** can help me get the latest file in the first row no matter how many pages I have.
[image]

If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know, thank you.

But if there are very large number of files, just for now, there isn't a good solution for it.

HTH.

Comment: I have tried that. It sorts within the page you are on. Perhaps it can do it when total number of objects are not too large. But like in my case, 50K+ objects, that kind of sorting doesn’t work.

Comment: Hi @smoshah  Per my experience, there isn't an easier way to do this. They are too large...

Comment: @smoshah We can wait for some days, if still with no new suggestion or reply,  can you please accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: hi @smoshah do you have any other concerns?

Comment: This should not have been marked as an answer, nor should the OP been pressured to do so. For many thousands of files, sorting by Last Modified simply does not work

Comment: Agree this is not the right answer, clicking on 'last modified' does not work for a large set of files

Comment: You will need to select 'all blobs and blobs without current version' option to see everything

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't quite work when you have a large number of blobs and each with varying versions.  If you truly want all blobs then in "Azure Storage Explorer" you need to select "All blobs and blobs without current version

[image]